# Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two finite sets having same cardinality. Show that a function $ f:A \to B $ is one-one if it is onto

Tags: functions

I have intuition of this statement but I don't have logical proof. How do we prove such statements in functions??

Comment: What definition of "same cardinality" are you working with?

Comment: @LeeMosher For finite sets, it shouldn't matter as each (*appropriate*) definition could be shown to be equivalent to each other.  You should safely be able to assume that he means there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that both $A$ and $B$ have exactly $n$ distinct elements in each.

Comment: Yes, one could write an answer with any given appropriate definition, but I dislike making such assumptions on an elementary level, I always like to know what the OP has in mind. It's mostly a moot point given the duplicate, but a smart questioner might have reason to question the answers in the linked duplicate.